# How does Eames get access to Fischer's office?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, inception

In the movie Inception, Cobb employs Eames for his Inception task as a forger. As a part of the task, Eames observes Browning and his behavior and mannerisms so he can forge his identity seamlessly during the course of the shared dream. Although Eames is just a forger, how does he get access to Fischer's office? 
In a scene where Browning is explaining Robert Fischer about the will and there is a heated argument, we see Eames is making notes of Browning's reaction. 
Does Saito have anything to do with such elevated access?

Answer (score 5):

The is alluded to in the script but not completely spelled out.  Immediately prior to seeing Eames at Fischer's office, we see him in a meeting with Cobb and Saito:

> **Eames**: Can you get me access to this man here?
>   Browning, Fischer Sr's right hand man. Fischer Jr's godfather.
>
> **Saito**: It should be possible. If you can get the right references.
>
> **Eames**: References are something of a specialty for me, Mr. Saito.

This implies that Saito uses his connections to get Eames a job directly with Fisher's organization or with some lawyers or consultants that would meet with Browning.

Eames's role as a 'forger' in the context of dream sharing is that he is an expert at impersonations and manipulating people.  I think we are meant to presume that he uses those skills to get himself into a meeting where he can observe Browning directly - by pretending to be a lawyer or business expert.

This may seem unlikely, but backed by Saito he may have the resources to do this.  All Saito has to do is to persuade or bribe someone to include Eames 'on their team' at a meeting.  All we see Eames do is sit, observe and take notes.

Answer (score 2):

Saito arranged it. Eames is impersonating a consultant for a legal firm representing Fischer, presumably as a temporary stand-in for someone who's off sick or otherwise detained. We don't see him doing anything more taxing than passing paperwork to the real lawyers.

> **SAITO:** *You fly out to Sydney on Tuesday. **We've arranged for you to spend several days...***
>
> INT. ANTEROOM, MAURICE FISCHER'S OFFICE - DAY
>
> Eames sits in the crowded room. Boxes and files are piled
> high. Browning stands by a pair of double doors.
>
> **SAITO (V.O.)**: ***...as part of a consulting litigation team working for Browning.***
>
> **BROWNING:** *I'm not smelling settlement here-we take them down.*
>
> **LAWYER:** *Mr. Browning, Maurice Fischer's policy is always one of avoiding litigation-*
>
> <sub><sup>[Inception: Screenplay](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Inception.html)</sup></sub>

Saito is a billionaire with sufficient clout to buy an airline if the need arises. Bribing a couple of people is basically nothing by comparison.